# How to associate mysql data to DataRepeater controls

Tags: c#, mysql, datarepeater

I have a [DataRepeater template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKGHA.png) control with 2 textboxes which I want to associate data from a `mysql` table

When I run this program I get the representation on my `DataRepeater` the number of rows existing in my `mysql` table

[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ov91.png)

my question is how to associate the data to those `textboxes`

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindLviewData();
    }

    protected void BindLviewData()
    {                  
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable("db.myTable");
            MySqlConnection dbConn = new MySqlConnection("Server = localhost; Database = db; Uid = wwww; Pwd = www; ");
            dbConn.Open();

            string query = string.Format("SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM myTable");

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbConn);
            MySqlDataAdapter returnVal = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            returnVal.Fill(dt);
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dt;
            dataRepeater1.DataSource = bs;

            dbConn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: The same way you would with any ADO.NET data source. This has nothing to do with MySQL. Did you check any ASP.NET tutorial that covers repeaters, like [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx)? There are a *lot* of them. They are old, because Data repeaters are old, available since 2005 at least. The simplest solution is to just use data binding syntax, `Text='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>'`

Comment: If you look for *Winforms* data repeaters, there are a lot of docs and tutorials too , like [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc425007(v=vs.80).aspx) from MSDN